# Is there a way of performing on-behalf-login using Google OAuth provider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-oauth, google-signin, google-openid

Is there any way of performing on-behalf of the user login in the context of OpenID? Ideally, I would like to create an OAuth 2.0 client at the Google Cloud Platform, grant access to that app and programatically login to an external webpage.

Right now I would have to use Selenium or similar framework to manually login to my Google account, grant consent, save cookies and query webpage directly the code.

But, I do not like the idea of hardcoding my GAccount's password and performing browser-like login. Is there a way how to use indirect (token based) login with a generic OAuth webpage?

I would like to scrape my account's data from external page behing Google's social login. I do not like the idea of login first to the google acccount and then granting access.

Rather I would like to have and backend app that would login to the web app and scrape it on my behalf using tokens.

I know how to use OAuth in the context of using Google APIs, but there is a lack of documentation when it comes to on-behalf-of usage from my perspective.